# If $-a+b|\tau|\cos(\arg(\tau)+k\theta)+c|\tau|^2\sin^2(\arg(\tau)+k\theta)<0$ holds for $k=\pm 1$, does it also hold for $k=0$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

I have points $\tau \in C$ that forms a convex set and satisfies the following inequality.
\begin{equation}
-a + b|\tau|\cos(\arg(\tau)-\theta)+ c |\tau|^2\sin^2(\arg(\tau)-\theta) < 0.
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-a + b|\tau|\cos(\arg(\tau)+\theta)+ c |\tau|^2\sin^2(\arg(\tau)+\theta) < 0.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
If $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied, whether the following inequality is true $(3)$?
\begin{equation}
-a + b|\tau|\cos(\arg\tau)+ c |\tau|^2\sin^2(\arg\tau) < 0.
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
It seems intuitively, the loci of all points that satisfies $(1)$ and $2$ represents the interior of a parabola ($\Bbb{P}$). So a point $\tau$ would represent a point rotated by an angle $\pm \theta$. Since the rotated point falls within the parabola, the actual point would be in the interior of the parabola which would imply $(3)$. I am not able to show it analytically.
The assumptions made are $arg(\tau) \in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R^+}$. The intuitive idea is given in the below picture.[image]

Comment: Any information about $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$. $\theta$ can take any value in the interval.

Comment: How about $a = 1, b = -3, c = 2, |\tau| = \frac{1}{2}, \arg(\tau) = \frac{3}{4}\pi, \theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$? It seems (1) holds but (2) fails.

Comment: If I make $b>0$, if $1$ holds, will $2$ follow up?

Comment: How about $a = 4, b = 9, c = 34, r = 2, \arg(\tau) = 7\pi/5, \theta = \pi/3$? You may do some numerical experiment to obtain examples easily.

Comment: Thanks for your counter examples. I have made few edits to the question. I am not sure, whether my intuition is true, until I see it analytically.

Comment: Do you mean for any $\tau$ in some convex set, (1) and (2) hold? Also, $a, b, c, \theta$ are fixed constants?

Comment: yes. $\tau$ are points in some convex set with eqn. (1) and (2) holds. with $a,b,c$ and $\theta$ are fixed constants.